# One login for 2 different angular apps on different domains

Tags: angular, angularjs, authentication

I want to create one login page for 2 already developed angular applications. They both use the same db and backend. An example: A user of site A comes to the login page and is redirected to the site A, then a user of site B uses the same login page to login and is redirected to site B, a different domain. Meaning after authentication each is redirected to A.com and B.com respectively.

I have considered SSO but this requires a user accessing site A first, then they are prompted to login and then granted access which means a user for site B would have to access site B to be able to access it. This did not give me the functionality i wanted.

I tried redirecting with an encrypted token to the respective site a user wants to access but the encrypted token, encrypted from the backend, is too long the angular routing throws an error.[image]

Is what am trying to do possible, if so how can I approach it.